# CSRF Vulnerability with top.location

Tags: javascript, html, csrf, csrf-protection

I have created one page with one form but i am not submitting that form. i have used javascript function for set top.location. when i test that page for Vulnerability i found that area show me CSRF Vulnerability with html form. can you please help me.

```
<form name="regForm" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <input type="hidden" name="regid">
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="display()">demo page</a>

<script>
  function display()
        {
            top.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
        }
</script>
```

I am not submitting that form so that i have not used CSRF token.

Comment: If you have a CSRF vulnerability, then it is not exposed by any of the code you put in the question. For there to be a CSRF vulnerability, you have to do something with user input, which you aren't doing here.

Comment: user just click on that link 'demo page'. there is no other user input. just can you please tell me that is there any vulnerability possible with top.location in java script.?

Comment: Yes, as with any other means to navigate a user or to get user input, it is possible for `top.location` to be involved in a CSRF attack.